# Flask SocketIO - Cannot emit events from server with gevent

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

My flask socketio server emits events properly with the default development server. But when I switch to gevent, no events are being emitted from server to client.

For example:

```py
import flask      
from __main__ import app, socketio

@app.route("/my-func", methods=["POST"])
def start_func():
  socketio.emit("start func") # Never gets emitted, skips right over
```

I have tried changing it to this, but it still doesn't work.

```py
import flask      
from __main__ import app, socketio

def emit_start_func():
  socketio.emit("start func")

@app.route("/my-func", methods=["POST"])
def start_func():
  socketio.start_background_task(emit_start_func) # Still doesn't work
```

This is how I setup my server:

```py
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import flask                                      
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="gevent")
app.secret_key = "secret"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8888
    print(f"* Running on http://{host}:{port}")
    WSGIServer((host, port), app).serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:
there's extensions.py in the same level as **init**.py of flask:
I initiated socketio here:

```
socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')
```

then in the **init**.py file I imported socketio from extensions.py.

and in my create_app() function, (note that: my flask app is written in application factory pattern) I added these:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/tools')
def on_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('task_completed', namespace='/tools')
def on_task_completed(data):
    print('Task completed:', data)
app.extensions['socketio'] = socketio
```

and finally the task that needs to run in the background:

```
from celery import shared_task

import time
from .extensions import socketio


@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def do_the_waiting():
    time.sleep(5)
    # with socketio.app.app_context():
    #     socketio.emit('task_completed', {'status': 'completed'}, namespace='/tools')

    socketio.emit('task_completed', {'status': 'completed'}, namespace='/tools')

    return None
```